# Nightmare Loop Through Click Events

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, nightmare

I'm learning Nightmare. Trying to visit a website, log in, and then click on a button iteratively to make more data appear until the button no longer exists. I have made a dummy account for illustration.

I have succeeded in logging in and clicking the button the first time, but when I try to have it click again it logs an error that it cannot find the '.more-checkins' element.

Ultimately, I would like this code to live in a loop rather than telling the code to click...wait...and click again. Help designing that would also be greatly appreciated.

```
const Nightmare = require('nightmare')
const untappdURL = 'https://untappd.com/user/beerFan2017'


Nightmare({
    show: true,
    openDevTools: true,
    waitTimeout: 90000000 // increase the default timeout to test things
})
    .goto(untappdURL)
    .click('.more_checkins')
    .type('#username', 'beerFan2017')
    .type('#password', 'Testing2017')
    .click('input[type="submit"]')
    .wait('.stats')
    .click('.more_checkins')
    .evaluate(function() {
        return console.log('Begin waiting');
    })
    .wait(5000)
    .evaluate(function() {
        return console.log('Waiting end');
    })
    .click('more_checkins')
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(error => console.error(error))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two-part answer: One, go read [asynchronous operations and loops](https://github.com/rosshinkley/nightmare-examples/blob/master/docs/common-pitfalls/async-operations-loops.md) on `nightmare-examples`.  That will help you get some background around iteration with promises.

Two, there is a similar issue in the Nightmare repo - [#625](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/625) - which has to do with continuing to load more when you reach the end of the scroll bar.  An example implementation (that is *very* naive, be careful):

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var vo = require('vo');
var nightmare = Nightmare({
  show: true
});

var run = function * () {
  yield nightmare.goto('http://someInfiniteScrollPage.tld');

  var previousHeight, currentHeight=0;
  while(previousHeight !== currentHeight) {
    previousHeight = currentHeight;
    var currentHeight = yield nightmare.evaluate(function() {
      return document.body.scrollHeight;
    });
    yield nightmare.scrollTo(currentHeight, 0)
      .wait(3000);
  }
  yield nightmare.end();
};

vo(run)(function(err) {
  console.dir(err);
  console.log('done');
});
```

Hopefully that gives you enough to get started.